# Kubernetes 1.2a: How can we add AWS instances of a different type to our cluster

Tags: kubernetes

With k8s version 1.1 I could copy the k8s launch config, change the instance type and then point my asg at the new lc to add other instance types to my cluster.

With version 1.2a8 there are 4 storage devices that don’t copy over… eg "DeviceName": "/dev/sdc”, "VirtualName": “ephemeral0”. Anyone know the best way to add instances of a different type to the k8s cluster in 1.2?
Looks like I have to update the block device mappings for the lc from the aws cli.

… and since you can’t modify a lc, I’d have to describe the k8s one and create a new one based on that description - which is a bit of a long way around this.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like because 1.2 is now gzip'ing the user-data there is a problem that the user data is changing when aws copies it to the new Launch Configuration. Even pasting the user-data in manually when copying the Launch Configuration still fails...

Update:
Copying it from the output of the aws cli (aws autoscaling describe-launch-configurations) into the new launch configuration in the console does work. (Making sure you check "Input is already base64 encoded" on the user-data input)